# In sqlplus how to change or specific file encoding to utf8

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

in sql plus I created a file :

```
>EDIT test.sql
```

the file encoding is ansi. I want to change it to ut8, I tried by save-as but it didnt work

how to change test.sql from ansi to utf8 in sql plus ?

Comment: On which platform, and which editor are you using?

Comment: @AlexPoole windows , sqlplus through cmd release 11.2

Comment: Which **editor** are you using? Notepad? Notepad++? Something else?

Comment: @mathguy notepad , by default sqlplus is opening windows notpad , i try by save-as to change the unicode but i am not able

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/557023/changing-the-default-ansi-to-utf-8-in-notepad I personally use Notepad++, a free and very good editor, with syntax highlighting including for SQL. It uses utf-8 by default.

Comment: are you trying to load this file into Oracle?  So is the problem with a conversion issue between the client and the database?  Still unsure what the issue is

Comment: @tbone I am not loading a file, I am using EDIT command , if you use edit command in sql plust it will create for you a file with ansi by default , i want to change it to ansi

Comment: @mathguy yes notepa++ is great editor but how to open notepad++ in EDIT command ? by default its notpad windows

Comment: SQL\*Plus has a very good user's guide on the Oracle web site, did you find it yet? It explains how to set your preferred editor. (Free hint: you do that in your `login.sql` file.)

Comment: @mathguy well my main question was how to change the encoding of a file through sqlplus .do you know how ?

Comment: My answer was a link to a Stack Overflow question about the same. And note that you don't change the encoding **through sqlplus**, that doesn't make sense. You do that in the editor you use. If you want to use Notepad, the SO item I linked to shows you how to do that.

Comment: @mathguy i cannot at the client dowlonad notepad++ , why I cannot change the encoding through notepad ? is it a bug ? is there restricition ? as i mentioned before , i click on save as change it to utf 8 and click save and i close the editor , when through sqlpluse write edit test.sql the file open but with ansi not utf8

Comment: Forget Notepad++. Did you follow the link I provided? The link is **not** about Notepad++, it is about plain Notepad.

Comment: @mathguy well i prefer not to modefy regestery as at the end he mention Remember: Modifying the registry is dangerous! Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change your default editor for sqlplus, you can do this:

1. logon to sqlplus
2. use "define" command to set the path to the new editor.  I like [TextPad](https://www.textpad.com/) (which handles utf8 automatically), so the command (for my machine anyway) would be:

   **define _editor="c:\Program Files\TextPad 7\TextPad.exe";**
3. Now, the edit command will bring up the new editor.

For TextPad, you can change the encoding by doing the following:

> Conversion: Conversion between various file formats and encodings can
>   be made using the Save As command on the File menu. The options for
>   encoding are ANSI, DOS, Unicode, Unicode (big endian) and UTF-8.

So after doing the steps above, edit will bring up Textpad, and using Save As you can save the file using various encodings.

This is one benefit of changing the default editor from Notepad.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I want to change the encoding